# linking vs 2012 c++ GDAL

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, gdal

I created a standard windows application with VS 2012 Pro.  Just a main.cpp that looks like this:

```
#include "gdal_priv.h"
#include "cpl_conv.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   GDALAllRegister();

    return 0;
}
```

I have set my include path properly.  I have gdal_i.lib in my Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies.

Link fails with the following message:

> 1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   _GDALAllRegister@0 referenced in function _main

(A scad of other symbols are missing as well, but this one should be easy.)

I used dumpbin and GDALAllRegister appears in the exported symbols.  It does appear as "GDALAllRegister", not as "_GDALAllRegister@0".

I tried downloading and using the dev build, and also built myself.  Same results.

I just know this is something simple, but I'm totally brain-cramping here.  What have I done wrong?

Thanks.

-reilly.

Comment: _GDALAllRegister@0
is the how the compiler chose to alias the constructor. I dont really know why its not linking but you could try using a fixed path just to see if it will build  ie. #inlcude "c:/pathto/cpl_conv.h"

Comment: What is your Calling Convention in C++->Advanced?

Answer (score 1):

I said it was simple and stupid, and it was.

I had the build manager set to build 32 bit.

Another 4 hours of my life I'll never get back.

Thanks to Manuell for his suggestion.  It got me looking in a different direction and I found it.

Sorry, community.  This is what comes from programming tired.

-reilly.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error is typical of a "Calling Convention" mismatch between EXE and LIB.

Check you have **__cdecl (/Gd)** in "Configuration Properties" -> C++ -> Advanced -> "Calling Convention"